# Cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type [String]

Tags: swift

I failed to append String by using following code:

```
(labGroups[labGroupIndex!].labs[labIndex!].tstDspGps[tstDspGpsIndex!].tests[testsIndex!]["specialReqValues"] as![String]).append("sdfsdf")
```

Error:

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type
>   '[String]'

And I can append value by using following code:

```
var arr = labGroups[labGroupIndex!].labs[labIndex!].tstDspGps[tstDspGpsIndex!].tests[testsIndex!]["specialReqValues"] as![String]    
arr.append("testValue")
```

However, it only affect the variable `arr`.

That is not what I want, when I print:

```
((labGroups[labGroupIndex!].labs[labIndex!].tstDspGps[tstDspGpsIndex!].tests[testsIndex!]["specialReqValues"] as![String]))
```

it still has nil value.

Can anyone help to solve this problem?

Comment: Your question title is misleading as it doesn't relate to your problem very well. You also haven't really provided enough of your code for us to help you. What is the type for `labGroups` for example? I can't tell if that is a variable, constant, array or dictionary.

Comment: Can you post full code here...then only it will be easy to us to find the solution.

Comment: One-liners like this don't generate faster code and can actually slow down compilation time - and they offer absolutely no advantage over a more readable, broken-down, multiline expression of the same logic.

Comment: The fact that you're ending in `as![String]` strongly suggests that you're using the wrong data structure for this. Whatever this final Dictionary is, at a minimum, convert it to a struct so that you have proper types and can attach methods. You may need to convert more of this to structs (in particular, Dictionary with String keys or Any values is often a mistake). That's the first step to getting this to work as expected.

Comment: You need to assign the result of the "snake" expression to a variable `var` before appending something.